# Код python не воспроизводит звук

Tags: python, pytorch, pyttsx3, tts

Программа должна озвучивать текст при помощи модуля Silero, а вместо этого выводит ошибку.

Код:

```py
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time
import silero

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'ru_v3'

sample_rate = 48000

speaker = 'xenia'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True

device = torch.device('cpu')

model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models_master',
                          model='silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                          speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)

def speak(what):
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=what+"..",
                            speaker=speaker,
                            sample_rate=sample_rate,
                            put_accent=put_accent,
                            put_yo=put_yo)
    
    sd.play(audio, sample_rate * 1.05)
    time.sleep((len(audio) / sample_rate) +0.5)
    sd.stop
speak('Привет')
```

а вот ошибка:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 267
    warnings.warn(
UserWarning: You are about to download and run code from an untrusted repository. In a future release, this won't be allowed. To add the repository to your trusted list, change the command to {calling_fn}(..., trust_repo=False) and a command prompt will appear asking for an explicit confirmation of trust, or load(..., trust_repo=True), which will assume that the prompt is to be answered with 'yes'. You can also use load(..., trust_repo='check') which will only prompt for confirmation if the repo is not already trusted. This will eventually be the default behaviour
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артём\Desktop\speak2.py", line 17, in <module>
    model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models_master',
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 539, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 203, in _get_cache_or_reload
    _validate_not_a_forked_repo(repo_owner, repo_name, ref)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 162, in _validate_not_a_forked_repo
    response = json.loads(_read_url(Request(url, headers=headers)))
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 145, in _read_url
    with urlopen(url) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: У Вас в ошибке говорится что какой-то пакет скачан не из доверительного репозитория, вряд ли я смогу без Вашей помощи сказать конкретно какой. Есть подозрения что `torch`. Попробуйте оставить только импорты в верху остальное заккоментировать выдаст ли в таком случае ошибку?

Comment: оставил только импорты, остальной весь код закомментировал, ошибок нету

Comment: тогда пропишите строку `device = torch.device('cpu')`, или раскомментируйте до нее включительно код.  если дело в `torch` то вероятно ошибка появится. — так мы пытаемся шаг за шагом найти какой из пакетов вызывает ошибку.

Comment: `device = torch.device('cpu')` эта строчка работает, но если добавить строчку
`model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models_master',` тогда снова появляется эта ошибка

Comment: возможно Вам стоит поправить код загрузки убрав из него слово `master` так `repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models'`  по крайней мере такой пример в [репозитории](https://github.com/snakers4/silero-models)

Comment: теперь такая ошибка 
https://pastenow.ru/MOG49

Comment: cкорее всего тут нужно почистить этот кэш, т.е. в данном случае удалить `snakers4_silero-models_master` папку из него

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/MOGDD
удалил папку, она пересоздалась заново и теперь такая ошибка

Comment: по сути та же ошибка что и в начале, мне нужно время поэксперементировать, если что получится напишу.

Comment: хорошо, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Пока опубликовал предварительный ответ, можете его проверить, так как у меня на данный момент еще не получается это сделать. точнее я не проверил конкретно `speak` часть кода до него исполняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка заключалась в проблеме с доверием к репозиторию, в тексте ошибки указано использовать флаг `trust_repo`. Так же перед запуском нужно обязательно почистить кэш в данном удалить случае папку `C:\Users\Apтём\.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master` - лучше найти вручную и подчистить.

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time
#import silero # вероятно это не нужно

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v3_1_ru' # другая версия русского
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'xenia'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True


device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id,
                                     trust_repo=True) # <- доверяем репозиторию

model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

def speak(what):
    audio = model.apply_tts(text=what+"..",
                            speaker=speaker,
                            sample_rate=sample_rate,
                            put_accent=put_accent,
                            put_yo=put_yo)
    
    sd.play(audio, sample_rate * 1.05)
    time.sleep((len(audio) / sample_rate) +0.5)
    sd.stop
speak('Привет')
```

Добавлю еще один способ загрузки модели указанный в документации:

```
import os

device = torch.device('cpu')
local_file = 'model.pt'

if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
    torch.hub.download_url_to_file('https://models.silero.ai/models/tts/ru/v3_1_ru.pt',
                                   local_file)  

model = torch.package.PackageImporter(local_file).load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
model.to(device)
```

В данном случае мы загружаем файл `model.pt` если его нет в папке с нашим скриптом, если он есть загрузки не будет, файл просто будет использоваться.

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло, я очистил кэш и добавил эту строчку кода такая ошибка:
https://pastenow.ru/MOL6W

Comment: почему-то не закачало модель снова, можете скинуть последнюю строчку сюда как текст? там где имя файла начиная с C:\

Comment: RuntimeError: open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen: No such file or directory, file path: C:\Users\Артём/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\model\v3_1_ru.pt

Comment: в таком случае предлагаю скачать Вам этот [файл](https://models.silero.ai/models/tts/ru/v3_1_ru.pt) самостоятельно и закинуть в эту дирректорию `C:\Users\Артём/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\model\` по идее ничего кроме этого файла больше не нужно.

Comment: Дополнил ответ еще одним способом загрузки модели, мне он понравился больше, можете попробовать его если не выйдет закинуть файл в кэш.

Comment: та же самая ошибка, файл уже был там, я заменил и всё равно такая же ошибка

Comment: Скажите, а Вы пробовали удалять (чистить кэш) эту папку  `C:\Users\Артём/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master` Просто тут он одновременно жалуется на кэш и отсутсвие файла. Я бы удалил кэш, так как из-за кеширования возникают трудноуловимые проблемы, не только в системе но и в браузерах.

Comment: Да, я полностью удалял эту папку, после запуска скрипта она снова создавалась и снова эта ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте тогда второй вариант которым я дополнил ответ, мне он понравился больше и думаю с ним будет меньше проблем так как это не требует кэша, файл просто появится в дирректории со скриптом

Comment: нужно поменять строки между `device = torch.device('cpu')` и `model.to(device)`

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь наконец-то заработало, очень благодарен)

Comment: Рад, что наконец-то получилось)

Comment: @DaniilLoban вы просто волшебник. Я уже 2 дня мучаюсь над этой проблемой. Дело было в том, что в пути присутствовала кириллица. У меня тоже по второму варианту прошло.

Comment: @QuL1ux, Рад, что помог. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)